# Find the basis of fundamental subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I was watching a video about linear algebra and computing the four fundamental subspaces.
The problem that was given in the video was the following:
Suppose
$$
    B=\left[\begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]   
 \left[\begin{matrix}
    5 & 0 & 3 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right] 
$$
Find a basis for and compute the dimension of each of the 4 fundamental subspaces.
Note: the matrix B is given in the B=LU form, if you have watched Gilbert Strang Lectures on Linear Algebra this form will make more sense.

They gave the solution:
Dimension of column space C(B)=2 (since there are two pivots)
A basis for C(B) is :
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    2  \\
    -1\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
     0  \\
     1  \\
     0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
$$

Dimension of row space $C(B^T)=2$

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
    5  \\
    0  \\
    3  \\
    \end{matrix}\right] 
\left[\begin{matrix}
    0  \\
    1  \\
    1  \\
    \end{matrix}\right] 
$$
Dimension of null space N(B) is 1 ( since there are 3 columns- number of independent columns which is 2)
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
    -5/3  \\
    -1  \\
    1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
$$
Dimension of left null space $N(B^T)=1$
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
$$

I can't understand how they got the values for the basis, and why they use matrix L to find the basis for the column space. If someone can clarify this to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The point is that matrix L is invertible while matrix U, with the last row all 0s, isn't. It is U, not L, that keeps   B from have a column space of dimension 3.  The product, B= LU, has column space of dimension 2.